# $\text{SU}(N)$ path-connected $\Rightarrow$ $\text{U}(N)$ path-connected

Tags: general-topology

Assume I can prove that $\text{SU}(N)$ is path connected. Can I use this to show that $U(N)$ is also path connected or won't that help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use that.

For $U \in U(N)$, let $\omega$ be its determinant. We have $|\omega|=1$, so $\omega = e^{i \phi}$, with $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$. We have a path from $U$ to an element $U_1$ in $SU(N)$
$$[0,1]\ni t \mapsto e^{-i t\phi/N}\cdot U$$

Now join $U_1$ to $I$ by a path in $SU(N)$. Put together, get a path from $U$ to $I$ lying inside $U(N)$.

Comment: I understand, but isn't there an $i$ missing in your map? And why we are dividing by $N$?

Comment: Alright, that's it :) Is there a similar way to construct a path in $\text{SL}(N,\mathbb{C})$ out of a path in $U(N)$? Maybe with $QR$ decomposition?

Comment: Why is the $Q$ part in $SU(N)$? The determinant may be $-1$, can't it?

Comment: Why are they $>0$? (They cannot be complex? We are working in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Got it now, but what do you mean by "You can deform the $R$ part into $I$"? I want to show that $SL(N,\mathbb{C})$ is path-connected, so I can't use this.

Comment: Yeah it make sense to me that I can do that and even that I can do that continuously. But is there a concrete path which does the job?

Comment: Maybe we take the path $[0,1]\to SL(N)$, $t\mapsto R'$ where $R'$ is the upper triangular matrix with $(1-t)R_{ij}$ for $i>j$ and.... what is $R'_{ii}$? $t+(1-t)R_{ii}$?

Comment: Why have you deleted your comments?